# Migrate from /net core 2.1 to .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting an error while migrating from .net core 2.1 to .net core 3.1

Error: The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher.  A FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.The app should be used instead and will be implicitly included by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.

Comment: There are step-by-step migration guides available at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio.

Comment: @juunas thanks now i am getting issue with  services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
            }).AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)

'JsonOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SerializerSettings'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am getting issue with services.AddMvc(options => {
>   options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
>   }).AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
>   Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize) 'JsonOptions' does
>   not contain a definition for 'SerializerSettings'

For asp.net core 3.0+,you need to install the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.1.0) for your version firstly,then replace

```
services.AddMvc()
 .AddJsonOptions(
    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);
```

with

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project

Comment: Thanks for this it solved my issue. 1more error i am getting related to cors
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
            });

it says alloworigin and allowcrediantials cannot be together. If i remove any one then when i open the application it says cors has blocked

Comment: @Harsha Mullangi I think it is another problem about CORS problem,maybe you could use `WithOrigins()` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-allowed-origins Besides, you need to put app.UseCors between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndPoints

Comment: but actually i want to allow all origins

Comment: @Harsha Mullangi Ok,in order to let more people see your new question,I suggest that you could mark the answer and open a new thread with more detailed startup code ,scenario and error info.It is hard to exactly know why you have this error

Comment: i have opened another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109800/cors-issue-while-migrating-form-net-core-2-2-to-net-core-3-0